# Infinite scroll label on SwiftUI principal toolbar item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple `NavigationView` that has a back button on its `navigationBarLeading`. For the `.principal` content, it will have a very large text. I would like that text to take only one line, and scroll infinitely horizontally (similar to what Instagram does for songs when they take more than device width).

Based on this [gist](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestRoundTripText.swift), I have been able to create a component that scrolls infinitely. However, the transition goes from one edge to the other, which overlaps with the toolbar items. How can it be updated so that the start and end points (`trailing` & `leading`) actually consider a padding on each side for the back button?

[image]

```
struct InfiniteLabel: View {
    let text: String
    
    @State private var go = false
    
    private let transition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    private let alignment = Alignment(horizontal: .myLeading, vertical: .center)
    
    @State private var reset = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(textContent)
            .fixedSize()
            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
            .animation(nil, value: go)
            .id(go)
            .transition(transition)
            .onAppear {
                go.toggle()
            }
            .animation(.linear(duration: animationDuration).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: go)
            .frame(alignment: alignment)
            .id(reset)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                reset.toggle()
            }
    }
    
    private var textContent: String {
        var result = text
        while result.count < 75 {
            result += " \(text)"
        }
        return result
    }
    
    private var animationDuration: Double {
        Double(textContent.count) / 7.0
    }
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
   private enum MyLeadingAlignment: AlignmentID {
      static func defaultValue(in dimensions: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
         return dimensions[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
      }
   }
   static let myLeading = HorizontalAlignment(MyLeadingAlignment.self)
}

struct InfiniteLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Main content of the view")
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    InfiniteLabel(text: "This is the long animation that should scroll")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to add more padding to the `Text`?

Comment: Where is the navigation stuff in your demo code?

Comment: @Yrb padding doesn't change the result

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini updated question to include previews.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
    var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        HStack {
            Text(textContent)
                .fixedSize()
                .animation(nil, value: go)
                .id(go)
                .transition(transition)
                .onAppear {
                    go.toggle()
                }
                .animation(.linear(duration: animationDuration).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: go)
                .frame(alignment: alignment)
                .id(reset)
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                    reset.toggle()
                }
        }
        .clipped()
        .offset(y: -5)
    }
}
```

You can play around with it to get it working a little more neatly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jason Cheladyn , but it isn't working if you a navigation bar trailing button